# controlling flash power on a 580EX using Godox x2t-c and x1r-c

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, godox

I am able to pair and trigger my canon 580EX without an issue using the camera shutter and the test button, but for the life of me the power on the flash will not change if i change it on my x2t-c. what could be wrong?

See below pictures of my flash, camera an trigger settings.
[image: settings on flash and receiver]

[image: settings on camera, canon eos r6]

Any advice is appreciated because at this point, i am looking at getting a Godox flash just so i can work without hassle.

Comment: Change Mode to Manuel on Godox transmitter and then adjust the power using the knob wheel on bottom left corner.

Comment: @Guest00001 Please see [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871). Your "comment" is clearly an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually pressing the shutter button to fire the flash before you look at the flash's control panel to see if the power has been changed? Also, which camera body is that?

Comment: The mode on the trigger and the flash is Manual. I have tried with the flash in off and master positions. I half press shutter button on the camera after flash power is changed using the knob wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canon 580EX is a very old flash that predates Canon’s introduction of the in-camera flash menu. If you use the 580EX in the your camera hot shoe, the in-camera flash menu will give you an error message. “this menu cannot be displayed. incompatible flash or flash's power is turned off"

[image]

Because of this I suspect the 580EX won't be fully compatible with the Godox X1R-C receiver. Godox reverse-engineered the hotshoe/camera menu communication protocol, so the X1R-C probably only has full compatibility with the flashes that can communicate with the Canon flash control menu. (430EX II, 580EX II, and later flash models, and RT flashes)

Comment: this may well be the case. guess its time for a new sppedlight. Thank you Mike

Answer (score 2):

I am using Godox X1T-C with 580EX and 580EXII.

X1T-C + 580EX does work in ETTL mode (including adjustable flash compensation setting), but does not work in manual mode.

X1T-C + 580EXII works in both ETTL and Manual modes. Note that it communicates f-stop, but not zoom (which you can set manually on the flash).